# Lorentz Transformation Geometric Interpretation

Tags: analytic-geometry, physics

So, I was recently trying to understand special relativity and from my understanding the Lorentz transformation can be framed mathematically as follows (we are assuming a reference frame moving at speed $v$ in direction of $x$)

Let $O=(0,0)$ of a 2-D co-ordinate system

Let a line $t'$ be defined as $y=\frac{c}{v}*x$ and a line $x'$ be defined as $y=\frac{v}{c}*x$

Now consider a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$

Through $P$ we draw a line $l$ parallel to $t'$ and let $Q=l\cap x'$

Then the new co-ordinate $x_0'$ is the distance OP along $x'$

So, the formula for the line $l$ is $y-y_0=\frac{c}{v}*(x-x_0)$

So, $y=\frac{c}{v}*(x-x_0)+y_0$

We equate for $Q\in  x'$

Now, we know that $Q_y=\frac{c}{v}*(Q_x-x_0)+y_0=\frac{v}{c}*Q_x$ , an equation which can be solved for $Q_x$ and $Q_y$

We know also that $OQ^2=Q_x^2+Q_y^2=Q_x^2(1+v^2/c^2)$

However evaluating this after solving yields $OQ=\frac{cx_0-vy_0}{c^2-v^2}*\sqrt{(c^2+v^2)}$

This yields $x'=\gamma(x-vt)*k$ where $k=\sqrt{(1-v^4/c^4)}$

Where on Earth did this extra factor come from?

Comment: I haven't read your question in full but the simplest and most elegant way to understand Lorentz transformations mathematically is as isometries of Minkowski space, that is $R^4$ with an indefinite quadratic form of signature (-+++), or equivalently (+---).

Comment: @GFR So, the classic diagram with two lines for the primed axis approaching 45 degrees at the limit $v=c$ is only approximate? Or did I make an algebraic mistake here?

Comment: "Through $P$ we draw a line $l$ parallel to $t'$ and..." Are you sure this is how it works? I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to accomplish with that derivation, but it reminds me of a contraption used by Henry Reich in his video series about SR, in [chapter 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh0pYtQG5wI&list=PLoaVOjvkzQtyjhV55wZcdicAz5KexgKvm&index=3) in particular, pause at 9:48 to get a better view of the internals. Do the hyperbolas look perfectly parallel to you?

Comment: But I was referring to the axis at 8:30 of that video to derive the equations. See in this video https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/special-relativity/lorentz-transformation/v/introduction-to-the-lorentz-transformation?modal=1

Comment: Never mind, I just realised that Pythagoras theorem doesn't apply here, so if you invert it by the rule $t^2-x^2=t'^2-x'^2$ then you get the right answer.